# Why pycharm community cant run my django app?

Tags: django, pycharm

So I've did:

```
$mkdir MyProject
$cd MyProject
$django-admin startpoject myproject
$cd myproject
$django-admin startapp myproject
```

Then I open pycharm, choosing open project using folder with file manage.py

Then I've created new python-configuration named myproject with scriptfile manage.py and parameter runserver, clicked on save and trying to run it but I got weird error:

> Error running 'myproject': Cannot run program
>   "/tmp/bitcoinprice.py/venv/bin/python" (in directory
>   "/home/blacknite/Fworld/Python/MyProject/myproject"): error=2, No
>   such file or directory

I dont understand, why pycharm tries to run some venv that is in some not related project of also not related with django parrent directory?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I got it.I guess when opening(NOT CREATING) new project pycharm still remember the last venv somehow, so it was all about creating venv for myproject and making it default one.